# Do you want to cover your head with festive headwear?

Tags: discussion

It's almost winter time (for those in the Northern hemisphere) and with that comes festive head wear.

Winter Bash 2016 will run from **19 December 2016** up to and including **08 January 2017**.

Leader boards will be available on the [Winter Bash 2016](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/) page soon.

The last [two](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1318/78) [years](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/191/78), we've participated and it seemed to go over well. We are opted in by default and if an individual user doesn't want to participate, they have the ability to opt out. If the entire community wants to opt out, we need to decide that here.

So the question is, do we want to participate again?

Comment: Six months on and bumped to the homepage.  Perhaps time for *status-completed*?

Answer (score 3):

## Don't be a hostile hothead, be a hat-style hat-head!

Comment: Is that a yes? (Really)

Comment: @JanDoggen yup!

Answer (score 2):

YES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I realize the ! are a bit excessive, but the answer had to be 30 characters long.

Comment: I'm sorry, this answer isn't in the form of a pun. [1](http://meta.communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/a/1319/78), [2](http://meta.communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/a/192/78)  Please try again

Comment: I figured tHat sparing people my horrible puns would be my holiday gift this year.

Comment: @Andy Even though AJ let us down, I still managed to **[continue the tradition](http://meta.communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/a/1347/42)** after several days of brainstorming. :p